# When to use である vs であります?

Tags: politeness, copula, formality, academic-japanese

I understand that である is the "written" form of だ/です. Because it's a "written" form, doesn't that already imply a certain level of formality? So when would one use であります as opposed to just である? If you can, please give examples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- である is **formal**, but **not polite**

  ---
- であります is **formal** *and* **polite**, but **not humble**
- でございます is **formal** *and* **polite** *and* **humble**

  ---
- だ is **informal**, but **not polite**
- です is **informal**-* *and* **polite**

  *- compared to である

  ---

A politician giving a speech on TV:

> 我々は日本国民**である** - We are Japanese citizens

A lawyer speaking to a judge: (I think this usage is rare though...)

> この通り**であります** - It (happended) this way

A waiter speaking to a customer:

> ざるそば**でございます** - (This) is zarusoba

One friend to another:

> ケチなやつ**だ**ね - That guys is really stingy, huh?

One coworker to another:

> すみません今ちょっと忙しい**です** - I'm sorry, I'm busy just now

Comment: Thank you, but could you explain the difference between formal and polite?

Comment: "Formal" is like for when you are in a public setting (like a speech or writing in a book or newspaper), "polite" is when you specifically want to show deference to the person you're addressing.

Comment: Wow, that is such a Japanese distinction. Thank you for the explanation, though I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around it. I suppose that's just something I'll get used to over time, haha.

Comment: There is also a practical, not-necessarily-formal use of である, unless I'm mistaken and everyone thought it would be rude to correct me when I use it (always a struggle). When I want to say I didn't know that something was something, I'll say something like this: トンカツは豚肉であることを知らなかった（I didn't know tonkatsu was pork). If that's not a valid use, here's a good chance to correct me :p

Comment: @Nick Overacker Using である when talking about the meaning of a word like that sounds natural to me because dictionary definitions and other written explanations often use である as well. I might suggest 「トンカツは豚肉のことであるとは知らなかった」(sounds a bit formal) or「トンカツって豚肉のことだったって知らなかった」(sounds very informal) as perhaps another natural-sounding way to say it.