# ことである in Japanese grammar

Tags: grammar, particle-が, particle-で, copula

Do こと**で**ある and こと**が**ある mean the same thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use である vs であります?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36305/when-to-use-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b-vs-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%82%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%99)

Comment: No, I think this is about ある vs だ.

Comment: I think he just doesn't know what である means (considering his title in particular), and there are already a plenitude of threads describing its usage. Anyway, it would help if he tells us what he thinks that they mean.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so.

`である` is basically equivalent to `だ` or `です` (the copula), so `ことである` can be replaced by `ことです`/`ことだ` where `こと` is either nominalizing the preceding expression, or is used as literal "thing/fact".

> これは大事なことだ
>
> This is an important matter.
>
> 大事なことがある
>
> [I] have something* very important. (*lit.* A very important thing exists.)

*Note: unlike similar `もの`, `こと` refers to intangible things.

Additionally, `ことがある` (or polite `ことがあります`) can describe either an event that happened in the past (with past form verbs), or something occurring with some regularity (with non-past forms).

> ～に何度か行ったことがある
>   [I] have been to ~ several times

This usage usually describes personal experience.

It cannot be replaced by `ことです` to express the same meaning.

> ～に何度か行ったことです
>
> Fact of the matter (?) is that [I] went to ~ several times*

*I'm not very sure it's a correct translation.

See also [The different usages of ことがある](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3977/)

References: *A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar* by Seiichi Makino, articles on **aru<sup>1</sup>**,**koto<sup>1</sup>**, **koto<sup>2</sup>**, **koto ga aru <sup>1</sup>**, **koto ga aru <sup>2</sup>**